# why does chvt work fine as a regular user on a virtual terminal, but not under X?

Tags: linux, security

When I'm logged in as user "paul" on a virtual terminal (/dev/tty2 for example) and I type in "chvt 4" I get switched over to the virtual terminal for /dev/tty4 just fine.

When, as user "paul" I type "chvt 7" I get switched over to the X window system.  Just fine.

HOWEVER...  Within an xterm, if as user "paul" I type "chvt 2" I get the following error:
"Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console"

The chvt command only works from within an xterm when I run it as "root", in which case, it's then happy to switch me over to a virtual terminal.

This seems very broken to me.  Does anyone know why this is as it is?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From a security point-of-view, recall that X is designed to be used over the network as well as at the physical console.  Virtual terminals aren't, so a login at the physical VT is a different security beast from X.

From [this Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=522453) on the same error in `fgconsole`.  Here's the breakdown of why `chvt` and friends can't access it from X:

> It doesn’t only affect fgconsole, but
>   also `chvt`, `openvt` and any other kbd
>   utility which tries to get a console
>   file descriptor. **These programs do
>   their job by trying to open/ioctl
>   these files (in this order)**:

```
/proc/self/fd/0         (is a pseudo tty in your case)
/dev/tty                (also PTY)
/dev/tty0               (only accessible to root)
/dev/vc/0               (doesn’t exist nowadays)
/dev/console            (root)
std{in,out,err}         (PTY)
```

> As none of these is able to respond to
>   a `VT_GETSTATE` ioctl, fgconsole and
>   friends fail.

The preferred solution to the issue is to use `sudo`.  There are other options but they are less preferable in the general case due to security issues -- you may decide your situation can tolerate one or the other (emphasis mine):

> > So there is no real solution, if I don't use sudo?
>
> You cannot change the permissions of `/dev/tty0` or `/dev/console` **without
>   opening a giant security hole**.  Setting the desired programs suid is an
>   option, but I’d stay away from it.  `sudo` is much safer and can be
>   controlled in more detail.

Comment: Wow... outstanding details as to why this is the way it is.  Thank you, ~quack!
<p>
Still it seems wrong to me that this doesn't work when DISPLAY is 0:0 or 0:N i.e. in the case where the X client is running locally.  
<p>
With X over a network DISPLAY would be 1:0...N, 2:0..N, etc. and yes from a security perspective any X clients not on 0:0..N should fail.  
<p>
It's just a shame that these programs fail when run from local clients without sudo.

Comment: it's just "hostname:x.y", and since "y" is usually "0" we can shorten it to "hostname:x". there's no local/remote difference -- the :N doesn't tell X anything about whether it's a remote or local display. for example, right now my server runs Xvnc on myserver:0.  if i wanted, i could configure it to run on myserver:2 instead -- that doesn't necessarily mean there's an x-server on myserver:0 and myserver:1 as well.  so X can't tell whether you're local or remote *just from the :N display number.*

Comment: I could be off on this but i thought the portion of DISPLAY to the left of the : identified the host?  So, 0 aka 0.0.0.0 aka localhost, or 127.0.0.1 and possibly some others would indicate localhost, meaning it's a local display.  I added NOPASSWD to sudoers and an alias or two so I can switch back and forth now seamlessly, but it's a hack.  Still perplexed re: why it wouldn't be possible to fix this.